# Android: how to send a httppost request after n dialog inputs

Tags: android, http, post, android-alertdialog

I have a method which retrieves an array of user requests. I iterate through this array, showing a `Dialog` with positive and negative buttons. When the last `Dialog` has been confirmed whether with yes or no, a `httppost` is sended to a server to process the data. I builded up the function like this:

```
private void processRequests(String resJSON){
    try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(resJSON);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Neue Herausvorderung");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        final int ARRAY_LENGTH = array.length();

        for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
            final String NAME= obj.getString("userName");
            final long ID= obj.getLong("userID");
            final int INDEX= i;

            builder.setMessage(name + " fordert dich zu einem Duell heraus! Willst du annehmen?");

            builder.setPositiveButton("JA", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    acceptedUsers.add(new User(ID, NAME));

                    if(INDEX== ARRAY_LENGTH-1){
                        sendRequestStuff();
                    }
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("NEIN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    declinedUsers.add(new User(ID, NAME));
                    if(INDEX== ARRAY_LENGTH-1){
                        sendRequestStuff();
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is, as soon as the first `Dialog` is confirmed, `sendRequestStuff()` gets called. I suspect the Listeners to cause the bug, but I am not sure. How can this be solved?

Comment: because the first dialog you will see is actually the last dialog, that means this condition will be true (INDEX== ARRAY_LENGTH-1)

Comment: let the condition to be if(INDEX==0) to send the data when the last dialog get answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send the request after getting a response from the last dialog: `if(INDEX== ARRAY_LENGTH-1)`.

Because you are running a loop over the whole array (from 0 to ARRAY_LENGTH-1) and show a dialog for each, the dialogs will be shown in this order: 0, 1, 2, 3, ...., ARRAY_LENGTH-1, which means that the last one that will be shown is ARRAY_LENGTH-1. This is the first dialog that you confirm/decline, and when you do it, you actually make a callback for `setPositiveButton` or `setNegativeButton`, and `(INDEX== ARRAY_LENGTH-1)` is `true`.

To solve this, just change the condition in the callbacks: `if(INDEX == 0)`.